# How to answer a question in the superlative form?

Tags: grammar, adjective, adjective-ending, question, comparison

**Wann machst du am liebsten Ferien, im Sommer, im Winter, im Herbst oder im Fruhling ?**

How can I answer the above question in a complete sentence.

I want to say that in winter is the best vacation.

Can I say

> Mein liebste Ferien ist im Winter

Is that correct ?

and if the question is

**Wo machst du am liebsten Ferien ?**

can I answer

> Mein liebste Ferien ist in Italien

Comment: In the question, *am liebsten* is an adverb while in your answer it is an adjective. Go figure.

Comment: so yes adjective ending should be st and then an e because Ferien is a feminine ?

Comment: No, you should stick with an adverbial *liebsten* in the answer.

Comment: AdVERB being the operative word.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments treat *am liebsten* as it should be, as a adverb (*liebste* is indeed a superlative form of *lieb*, but not really seen as such here).

Then your answer should contain *am liebsten*, just as if it were *gerne*. And you don't worry about the endings.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other comments and answers that say you should keep *am liebsten* as an adverb (like *gerne*) in the answer

> *Ich mache **am liebsten** im Winter Ferien.*
>   *Ich mache **am liebsten** in Italien Ferien.*

(*Ferien machen* is used as a synonym for the more common expression *in den Urlaub fahren* here. In the following you may also substitute *Ferien* by *Urlaub(s)*.)

It’s of course possible to use the superlative as a proper adjective (like *bevorzugt+*) instead of an adverb:

> *Meine **liebste** Ferienzeit ist der Winter.*
>   *Mein **liebstes** Ferienziel ist Italien.*

Actually, in such cases *Liebling* is often used to form compounds instead:

> *Meine **Liebings**ferienzeit ist der Winter.*
>   *Mein **Liebings**ferienziel ist Italien.*